# How to use UNPIVOT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `StoreDetails` with the following data.

```
 Store  1       2       3
-------------------------------
101     138     282     220
102     96      212     123
105     37      78      60
109     59      97      87
```

My required output is:

```
Store       Week        xCount
---------------------------------
101         1           138
102         1           96
105         1           37
109         1           59
101         2           282
102         2           212
105         2           78
109         2           97
101         3           220
102         3           123
105         3           60
109         3           87
```

How can I get this result set using `UNPIVOT`?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using `cross apply`:

```
select sd.store, v.week, v.xcount
from storedetails sd cross apply
     (values (1, sd.[1]), (2, sd.[2]), (3, sd.[3]), (4, sd.[4])
     ) v(week, xcount);
```

Why do I prefer `apply` over `unpivot`?  `unpivot` is *very specific* syntax that does only one thing (and is specific to SQL Server and Oracle).

On the other hand, `apply` is an introduction to lateral joins.  These are very powerful and unpivoting is just one thing that they can do.

Comment: I agree that apply is more powerful, however there's a difference between using unpivot and cross apply: the unpivot will filter null values after unpivoting while the cross apply won't (unless you filter it specifically).

Answer (score 3):

you can try below-

```
select store,week, xcount
from StoreDetails
unpivot
(
  xcount for week in (1,2,3)
)up
```

Comment: This will only convert the rows into column format. It's not giving the required output mentioned in the question.